# Mongo Aggregation of Field Names

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have some Mongo data of the form:

```
{
  "content": "Foo",
  "metadata": {
    "key1": "value",
    "key2": "another value",
    "key3": "and another value"
  }
}
```

The keys in the metadata subdocument could be named anything (I've called them `key1`, `key2` and `key3` above, but they could be called `author`, `title` and `date` for example). There will be an unknown number of them, and the names may also be unknown.

Is there an (aggregation?) query I can run to list all of the fields in the metadata subdocument, across all of the documents in my collection?

Comment: *an unknow number of them*: That is the source of your problems. You should consider to make "metadata" an array of subdocuments. Btw don't use the [`mongodb-aggregation`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337096/let-burninate-mongodb-aggregation) tag.

Comment: The MapReduce approach seems to require creating a new (temporary) collection - is there no other way of doing it? The data and hence the fields are likely to be changing frequently, so I'd rather have it returned from a query that can be run than having to keep building new collections.